# Simple save to JSON file with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I've tried out all examples I could get my hands on, yet I can't simply save JSON data to a JSON file on my host. I want to start with a simple as possible save method so I have a place to start from.

**Here's what I got:**
Basically I have a button in my **index.html** which on click should save data to my general.json file (same location as index.html).

```
<button id="savebtn">Save</button>
```

With id selector in a **myscript.js** I do this:

```
$('#savebtn').click(function() {
                var saveit = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');

        var eventsholded = [];

    $.each(saveit, function(index,value) {
        var event = new Object();
        event.id = value.id;            
        event.start = value.start;
        event.end = value.end;
        event.title = value.title;
    event.allDay = value.allDay
        eventsholded.push(event);
    }); 
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        dataType : 'json',
        async: false,
        url: 'general.json',
        data: JSON.stringify(eventsholded),
        success: function () {alert("Thanks!"); },
        failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
    });
```

As you can see I want to store events from fullcalendar. That is not very relevant because it works fine till this point.
**If I alert on screen JSON.stringify(eventsholded)** you will see this:

```
[{"start":"2014-01-07T08:30:00.000Z","end":"2014-01-07T12:30:00.000Z","title":"Pumukli Pista","allDay":false},{"start":"2014-01-11T13:30:00.000Z","end":"2014-01-11T18:30:00.000Z","title":"Fanic Catalin","allDay":false}]
```

Now **this is exactly what I want to save to server in simple, quick, maybe unsecure, but very simple way.** Just so I can start to understand how this works, just to have that in my general.json file.

The `$.ajax` part does nothing in my above code. Not even alerting "Error". The rest of the code works as expected.

**Security is not important now.** I just want to learn how it works.

**I will be grateful for any help or useful links that have complete examples. Thank you!**

Comment: I don't think you can save to a file that way as you'll need a web-server on the other end which would do the saving (or maybe you have that and I'm must not seeing it). But what I do notice is that you are referring to `general.json` as an object `general` with an attribute `json`, rather than the file name 'general.json'. If you open your console, you will probably see an error message 'general.json is undefined' or something similar. That is why you aren't getting the error.

Comment: `url: general.json` is a mistake in my question. Edited now. Well I can read a json file so I would like to know how to write one. I have **all this hosted on a webserver and I develope using XAMPP**. Now I'm looking for ways to achieve saving/writing to this .json file.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`$.ajax` alone will not save the json file, you need to direct the `url` property to a server-side script, i.e. `http://your.host/save_json.php`, that will create `general.json` and write your output on it. Something like:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$myFile = "general.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET["data"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh)
?>
```

You'll also need to change the `data` property in your `ajax` call to `data: {data: JSON.stringify(eventsholded)}` to give the GET variable a proper name that can be retrieved from PHP:

**JQUERY**

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        dataType : 'json',
        async: false,
        url: 'http://your.host/save_json.php',
        data: { data: JSON.stringify(eventsholded) },
        success: function () {alert("Thanks!"); },
        failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
    });
```

Comment: You may want to use post rather than get (on both the ajax and php) so you aren't trying to send the entire file in a URL param.

Comment: Ok. Now it is creating the general.json file, however it is empty. I try to get my head around that. By now this seems to be thw right way.

Comment: I go nuts. Can't pass the value. I don't know if the php is not getting the value or the created general.json file :(

Comment: did you add the object to the data property? check the updated answer.

Comment: I never thought it should be `data: {data: value to pass}`. You need more rep points. Thank you very much!