# jquery ajax object doesn't want to store variables

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object

i'm trying to use jquery ajax to store some json data in a table.
I've come so far that I can add data manually to the .json document and the content shows up in the table. But i'm trying to make this possible by making an input in my html-file. I'm trying to get the value from the input text into my js-file but the object won't simply store the variables for some reason.

I've edited the code several times already and I'm lost. Any help is appreciated.

```
$(function(){

    var $name = $("#name").val();
    var $age = $("#age").val();
    var $town = $("#town").val();
    var $aircraft = $("#aircraft").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../content/json/members.json",
        success: function(data) {
            flight = JSON.parse(data);
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < flight.length; i++) {
                tr = $("<tr/>");
                tr.append("<td>" + flight[i].name + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + flight[i].age + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + flight[i].town + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + flight[i].aircraft + "</td>");
                $(".members").append(tr);
            }
        }
    });

    $(".sendButton").on("click", function() {

        var postMember = {
            name: $name,
            age: $age,
            town: $town,
            aircraft: $aircraft,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",   
            url: "../content/json/members.json",
            data: postMember,
            success: function(postMember) {
                addMember = JSON.parse(postMember);
                tr = $("<tr/>");
                //$.each(addMember, function(i, attribute) {
                tr.append("<td>" + addMember.name + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + addMember.age + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + addMember.town + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + addMember.aircraft + "</td>");
                //});           
                $(".members").append(tr);
            }       
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You'll need a server-side page which receives the "add" request, writes the info into the JSON file, saves it, and sends back the file's contents. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948155/simple-save-to-json-file-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are capturing the input values at the beginning and not when the user submits the form when they click button with '.senButton' class.

You need to move this:

```
var $name = $("#name").val();
var $age = $("#age").val();
var $town = $("#town").val();
var $aircraft = $("#aircraft").val();
```

Inside the '.sendButton' click event so it capture the current value of each input field:

```
$(".sendButton").on("click", function() {
    var $name = $("#name").val();
    var $age = $("#age").val();
    var $town = $("#town").val();
    var $aircraft = $("#aircraft").val();
```

Will that fix your issue?

Comment: I tried this now and although it didn't solve my issue completely, my table cells has been updated with an 'undefined' error. So there's progress at least :)

Comment: @user3361858 alert $name etc and is your alert also undefined or have the correct value?

Comment: The alert is empty I'm afraid.

Comment: If you wrote something in that input and it is empty, it could mean that the selector is wrong? Double check the selectors ($("#name") etc, check the input actually has id 'name' and not class; has happened to me enough times) and that they are all correct. Alert again. Still empty even though you wrote something to it?

Comment: Well, the selectors was in the wrong place. i've put them in my div:s and not in my input type. So i placed them where they should be and when doing the alert again, I now get the value that was typed in. But new input in the table still say 'undefined'.
But getting close...I can feel it.

Comment: Last test before you need to start blaming the code inside "../content/json/members.json". Put this code just after initialising 'postMember' object: alert(JSON.stringify(postMember)); If that also returns the input values you expect, start investigating the code inside "../content/json/members.json".

Comment: To test the response from the ajax call, put after this: 'success: function(postMember) {', this code 'alert(JSON.stringify(postMember));'

Comment: The first stringify returns the input value from my form.
The second strangely returns the data that is already in my table. Was expecting the new input value there as well.

Comment: Double check the "../content/json/members.json" is working as you expect as it sounds that is to blame if your input (first alert) is correct but output is not (second alert).

Comment: Tip for future in case you did not know: in chrome and firefox you can go to development tools (F12) and (on chrome) if you go to "Network" tab and select sub tab "XHR", you can see your ajax calls. If you click on any of the calls, it will show up header details that includes what you sent to other page and response details that also include the details your browser received from that other page.     No need for alerts anymore.

Comment: Additional tip to remove the need of alerts for debugging: use console.log('input!') and other console.* functions. Those will print the 'input!' to console that you can find in developer tools' console (F12 if not open already => console)