# Modify a local json file

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

First of all I would like to say sorry, if my question would be very simple, but I don't have huge experience. I have read a lot of information but still have a problem.

I'm using jQuery Ajax to modify a local json file. When I try to GET information from that file there is no problem, but when I try to POST some new things to it, I got error 404.

```
js\main.js
var obj = {"name": "john", "date": "20.08.2017"};


$.ajax({
  url: 'js/dane.json',
  dataType : 'json',
  type : 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(obj)
}).done(function(response){
        console.log("ok");
}).fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
});

js/dane.json

json file:
{  
 "results": [
   {
      "name": "Harvey",
      "date": ["12-08-2017"]
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write JSON into local storage and just use JSON.stringify (non-jQuery) to serialize a JavaScript object. You cannot write to any file using JavaScript alone. Just cookies or local (or session) storage.

```
var obj = {
    name: 'john',
    date: "20.08.2017"
};
```

localStorage.setItem('jsonData', JSON.stringify(obj));
And to retrieve the object later, such as on page refresh or browser close/open...

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jsonData'));
```

If you still want to write the file. Then you must have to use server side scripting language such as `PHP` [More server side scripting languages are here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2072a9/client-side-vs-server-side-programming-languages/)

This answer will help you more to know how to write file using `PHP` 
[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948155/simple-save-to-json-file-with-jquery)